# Docker install fails for numpy - miniconda

Tags: docker, miniconda

Below is my Dockerfile. It keeps failing with the following error when trying to install.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN pip3 install mlflow>=1.0 \
    && pip3 install numpy==1.14.3 \
    && pip3 install scipy \
    && pip3 install pandas==0.22.0 \
    && pip3 install scikit-learn==0.19.1 \
    && pip3 install cloudpickle \
    && pip3 install boto3
```

Error:

```
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 675, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

Comment: because you are using a miniconda image, can you use `conda` to install packages instead?